# Python Selenium Change Element Class/Attribute

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

There's this element which manually I click so I can fill out the form and generate a file for download.

[image]

As I said, manually it's a clickable element that works just by clicking it. Here's the problem:
Clicking-in the element won't work, selenium is giving me the type of error saying the element is not iterable, I've tried also tried changing the 'class' attribute, which by what I saw, is what changes in the Html when I click it with Chrome prompt opened.

This is the HTML without clicking it(second image):
[image]

This is the Html when I click it(third image):
[image]

edit 14/01/2022 09_54:

The code i tried was:

```
element = ''

while element == '':

    try:

        element = nvg.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/label[2]')

    except:

        element = ''

"""so after this loop it is actually able to find and referenciate the element"""

nvg.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]'
'/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/label[1]').__setattr__('class', "fancy_radio inline fancy_unchecked")

print(element.get_attribute('class'))
"""it prints the 'fancy_radio inline fancy_checked' string"""

element.__setattr__('class', "fancy_radio inline fancy_checked")
"""returns and changes nothing"""

element.click()
"""raises the not iterable element"""
```

Comment: maybe you are using `driver.find_element()` instead of `driver.find_elements()`
Can you share your code and error?

Comment: No, i can actually refer to the element, get it's text and stuff, but i can't 'click' in it, for it's not a button type element. I can get properties from it, just like the class str, so it is as it seens not a reference problem, the element is there, selenium is able to get the handle of it.

Comment: for this `Clicking-in the element won't work, selenium is giving me the type of error saying the element is not iterable,` which code did you try ?

Comment: element.click()(returns not iterable element error), element.submit()(returns nothing), element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER or Keys.SPACE)(returns nothing).

Comment: @AJR can you share your code please?

Comment: Just did, course i can't post the whole code, like the link and stuff.